# ES2015 arguments destructuring error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying too destructure the following function:

```
import { CHANGE_MSG, INCREMENT_COUNTER } from './mutation_types'

export const changeMessage = (store, msg) => {
  store.commit(CHANGE_MSG, msg)
}
```

this way :

```
// ES2015 arguments destructuring
changeMessage ({ commit }, msg) {
  commit (CHANGE_MSG, msg)
}
```

however eslint is raising an error on '{'

```
Parsing error: unexpected token , [js] expected ;
```

what's wrong with my coding ?
thanks for feedback

Comment: Does it work, and it's just a linting error, or doesn't it work at all?

Comment: this is not equivalent, you'll lose `this` in `commit`

Comment: other than that, works for me: https://repl.it/Kdaw

Comment: sorry .. got it .. forgot the export ! see my answer .. destructuring this way is OK..  enjoy your day !

Answer (score 1):

Cut and  paste issue , forgot to code the export statement 
it runs this way :

```
import { CHANGE_MSG, INCREMENT_COUNTER } from './mutation_types'

export default {
  changeMessage ({ commit }, msg) {
    commit(CHANGE_MSG, msg)
  },
  incrementCounter ({ commit }) {
    commit(INCREMENT_COUNTER)
  }
```

}